# Flutter Bloc: BlocBuilder not getting called after an update, ListView still displays old data

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using flutter_bloc for state management and landed on this issue. When updating a field and saving it, the BlocBuilder is not refreshing the page. It is working fine when Adding or Deleting. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Even if I go to a different screen and returning to this screen it still displays the old data even though the file was updated.

I spent more than 2 hours trying to debug this to no avail. I tried initializing the `updatedTodos = []` then adding each todo one by one, to see if that does something, but that didn't work either.

Any help here would be appreciated.

TodosBloc.dart:

```
Stream<TodosState> _mapUpdateTodoToState(
    TodosLoaded currentState,
    UpdateTodo event,
  ) async* {     
        if (currentState is TodosLoaded) {
        final index = currentState.Todos
            .indexWhere((todo) => event.todo.id == todo.id);
        final List<TodoModel> updatedTodos =
            List.from(currentState.todos)
              ..removeAt(index)
              ..insert(index, event.todo);

        yield TodosLoaded(updatedTodos);
        _saveTodos(updatedTodos);
      }
  }
```

todos_screen.dart:

```
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _todosBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, TodosState state) {
        List<TodoModel> todos = const [];
        String _strings = "";
        if (state is TodosLoaded) {
          todos = state.todos;
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: todos.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctnx, int index) {
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(todo.toString()),
                child: DetailCard(
                  todo: todos[index],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
...
```

I'm expecting when the BlocBuilder to be called and refreshed the ListView.

Answer (score 20):

I was able to resolve this with the help of Felix Angelov on [github](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/197). 
The problem is that I'm extending Equatable but not passing the props to the super class in the TodoModel class. I had to update the constructor of the TodoModel with a super([]).

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, but I'm not extending my model class with Equatable. I have no idea how to fix this. I really feel like I'm using flutter_bloc "correctly". Seems like a design flaw with this particular library.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i solved the issue , even though it could not be the best solution but i'll share it , when you are on the other screen where you are supposed to show data or something , upon pressing back button call dispose as shown below

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   print("id" + widget.teamID);
   BlocProvider.of<FootBallCubit>(context).getCurrentTeamInfo(widget.teamID);
 }

 // what i noticed upon closing this instance of screen , it deletes old data
 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
   Navigator.pop(context);
 }
```