# BLoC with freezed - yield does not emit state change to widget

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc, freezed

With a state change observer I can see that my bloc changes its states to `LoadInProgress` and back to `PmLoadSuccess`. However, the widget is not called with the change to `LoadInProgress`. I have a breakpoint in the `BlocBuilder`, however, the code stops there only when `PmLoadSuccess` is emitted.

My state definition

```dart
@freezed
class ProblemManagerState with _$ProblemManagerState {
  const factory ProblemManagerState.initial() = PmInitial;
  const factory ProblemManagerState.loadInProgress() = PmLoadInProgress;
  const factory ProblemManagerState.loadSuccess(
      Problem problem) = PmLoadSuccess;
      ) = PmSyncFailed;
}
```

The bloc

```dart
@injectable
class ProblemManagerBloc extends Bloc<ProblemManagerEvent, ProblemManagerState> {
  final IProblemsRepository problemsRepository;
  ProblemManagerBloc(this.problemsRepository) : super(PmInitial());

  @override
  Stream<ProblemManagerState> mapEventToState(
    ProblemManagerEvent event,
  ) async* {
    yield PmLoadInProgress();  // <<< does not emit to widget 
    yield* event.map(
      pmProblemRequested: (e) async* {
        yield ProblemManagerState.loadInProgress();  // <<< doesn't emit either 
        print (state);
        yield* _mapPmProblemRequestedToState(e);
      },
    );
  }

  Stream<ProblemManagerState> _mapPmProblemRequestedToState(/*PmProblemRequested*/dynamic event) async* {
    dynamic nextProblem;
    late int problemClassId;
    problemClassId = event.problemClassId!;
    }
    final String rootId = await _getNextProblemRootId(problemClassId);
    final Either<StorageFailure, Problem> failureOrProblem = await problemsRepository.getProblem(rootId);
    yield failureOrProblem.fold(
            (fail) => PmLoadFailure(fail),
            (load) => PmLoadSuccess(load)); // <<< yield does emit to  widget
  }
```

The widget (calling another widget if load successful)

```dart
class ProblemManagerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ProblemManagerBloc, ProblemManagerState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return state.map(  // <<< breakpoint not reached with PmLoadInProgress (=ProblemManagerState.loadInProgress)
              initial: (_) => Container(),
              loadInProgress: (_) => const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
              loadSuccess: (state) => PmGateway(state.problem),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503807/flutter-bloc-blocbuilder-not-getting-called-after-an-update-listview-still-dis

Comment: yes, but that is about Equatable. I am using freezed instead and there is no overriding the props (I know of). I have followed the DDD tutorial of Reso Coder https://github.com/ResoCoder/finished-flutter-firebase-ddd-course/blob/master/lib/application/notes/note_watcher/note_watcher_bloc.dart

Comment: I have changed this from freezed to Equatable. No change... Could this be caused because the BlocBuilder of this bloc does not directly render anything and because the Widget called by the Widget `PmGateway` (seen in the snippet above) has its own bloc which does not emit a new state? I was expecting that if the root bloc emits a new state that does not rebuild the child widget with its bloc, the child widget vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [github issue list](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2260#issuecomment-804601966)

> This is expected because BlocBuilder can only rebuild at 60fps. In this case you are emitting states faster than BlocBuilder can rebuild.